# doGet calls doPost OR vise versa

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I've bring this example from a book:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException
  ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
  out.setContentType(“text/html”);
  out.println("<html><h1>Output to Browser</h1>");
  out.println("<body>Written as html from a Servlet<body></html>");
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException
  doPost(req, resp); //call doPost() for flow control logic.
}
```

***Questions:***

1. *Why `doPost` can't call `doGet`?*
2. *What does `flow control` mean?*

Comment: The author could EITHER have made doPost call doGet OR doGet call doPost, since both are intended do the same task.  It makes no difference which one he or she chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `doGet()` from `doPost()` and vice-versa. No issues. But, you should not do such things. Both the methods have different purpose.

Ideally, the pre-processing task has to be done in `doGet()` method. For example, suppose you want to validate where a *user* has logged in or not, before forwarding the request to the user home page, that you would do in `doGet()` method. While the post-processing task has to be done in `doPost()`. For example, when a user submits a form, then you would like to get the values that are in the form, and validate them. Such logic go in `doPost()` method.

You should not mix them. If they were the same, there wouldn't be need of both methods. For more details on those methods see our [servlet](/questions/tagged/servlet) tag wiki.

Answer (score 2):

The example mean all the request whether it is `GET` or `POST` it will be going to be handle by the single method.You can move the `doPost` code to `doGet` and call `doGet` method from `doPost`,thr will be no issue.

Comment: @jgitter hehhehe its ohk dear

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old, but still...

About Q1, everybody gives a really interesting and exact answer but the truth is out there... Just take a look at this "minified" code, you will understand:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
  doPost(req, resp);
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
  //
  //Do something
  //
  //Can I call doGet() ?
}
```

Yes it is an infinite loop if you do so: doPost call doGet that call doPost that call doGet...

Answer (score 1):

If you need the doGet calls doPost, then it is better to use the "service".

```
protected void service((HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws  ServletException, IOException { 
     //do something you need
}
```